# Infinite series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of $$\frac{2}{4-1}+\frac{2^2}{4^2-1}+\frac{2^4}{4^4-1}+\cdots \cdots $$

Try: write it as  $$S = \sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{2^{2^{r}}}{2^{2^{r+1}}-1}=\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{2^{2^r}-1+1}{(2^{2^r}-1)(2^{2^r}+1)}$$

d not know how to solve from here, could some help me

to solve it, Thanks

Comment: $$\dfrac a{a^2-1}-\dfrac a{a^2+1}=\dfrac 2{a^4-1}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think he had the right side and wrote the left one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may continue as:

$$\frac{2^n}{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)} =\frac{(2^n+1)-1}{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)} =\frac 1{2^n-1} - \frac 1{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)}$$
Where $n = 2^r$. Now write the sum as:

$$\left(\frac 11 - \frac 13\right)  + \left(\frac 13 - \frac 1{15}\right) + ... + \left(\frac 1{2^n-1} - \frac 1{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)}\right)$$

After cancelling the terms you are left with:

$$1 - \frac 1{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)}$$

When $n$ tends to infinity, the expression becomes $1$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Note that [mathematical notation can be properly typeset in posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which makes them easier to read.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In the solution , $n=2^j$ , so the pattern does indeed follow , as $$\frac{1}{2^2^{j+1}-1}=\frac{1}{(2^2^j+1)(2^2^j-1)}$$ . While the solution should have mentioned this , I hope this clears it up .

Comment: @Rahuboy For future reference you can't do double exponentials without braces, e.g. $2^{2^{j+1}}$ is `2^{2^{j+1}}`, not `2^2^{j+1}`. That's why your comment malfunctioned.

Comment: @J.G. Oh I see.... thanks for the help !

Comment: That is embarrassing. My apologies for failing to realize this.

Answer (score 7):

You may prove by induction that $$\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{2^{2^r}}{2^{2^{r+1}}-1}=1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n+1}}-1}.$$(If yoiu didn't spot this conjecture at first, you will after calculating the first few partial sums.) Indeed the claim is correct if $n=0$, and if it holds for $n=k$ then $$\sum_{r=0}^{k+1}\frac{2^{2^r}}{2^{2^{r+1}}-1}=1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k+1}}-1}+\frac{2^{2^{k+1}}}{2^{2^{k+2}}-1}=1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k+2}}-1}$$as required, where the final calculation is the $a=2^{2^{k+1}}$ special case of $$1-\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{a}{a^2-1}=1-\frac{1}{a^2-1}.$$You may wish to rewrite this argument as the computation of a telescoping series.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that
$$
\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}-1}=2^{-n}\frac{1}{1-2^{-2n}}=\sum_{k:\text{odd},k\in\Bbb N} 2^{-nk}.
$$ If we sum over $n=2^j$, $j\ge 0$, we have
$$
S=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2^j}}{2^{2^{j+1}}-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k:\text{odd},k\in\Bbb N} 2^{-2^j\cdot k}=\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2^{-l}=1
$$ since every $l\ge 1$ has a unique representation $l=2^j\cdot k$ for some $j\ge 0$ and odd $k\in \Bbb N$.